# NFS, rsync or other to avoid installing ftp on secure remote Asterisk PBX server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asterisk

Two VPS hosts:

One has everything on it - mail, web, ftp, dropbox and so on.
The other is an Asterisk PBX (VOIP server) installation which is locked right down. Nothing except Asterisk runs on it, and the only ports open are the bare minimum to allow Asterisk and sshd to function.

Let's say I wanted to allow users to upload and downloading various files from using ftp or dropbox on the "insecure" web server.

On Asterisk, I have the following folders which I want to share onto the "user facing" server.

- logs - I want end users to be able to READ but not alter or
  delete them.
- audio - I want users to be able to add or remove audio files
- voicemail - I want users to be able to download and delete the
  voicemail files.

I do not want users to be able to delete or otherwise modify the directory names, nor do I want them to be able to traverse above those directories.

Possibly worse still, Asterisk is running as "root", hence the files and directories are root owned too. The person who helped me set it up and secure it says this is normal, but at that stage this idea of other directories wasn't known about.

After most of a day of mind being boggled, it seems to come down to rsync or nfs.
The problem is, I don't fully understand the risks of both, and the more I read, the more certain I am to be opening up a portal of doom into my Asterisk box.

(For avoidance of question closing, this isn't a question about "what is the best way, please debate", this is a question of "what is the RIGHT way, and why?".
I know it's all semantics, but sometimes it helps!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what Asterisk log files should be user facing, or what read-only audio files (outside of voicemail)...so it's hard to guess what you are doing.  But I'll make some assumptions:

If your goal is to keep end-users off the Asterisk box that's great.  You could rsync / scp files to the user facing system (as these protocols provide a lot of security).  NFS would work as well but offering mount points for the OS isn't as secure.

If you are worried about hacking of your Asterisk box, then this is the wrong approach.  90% of PBX attacks (and almost all financial loss) are through SIP - so unless you limit SIP port access to known fixed IP's (and more), you aren't making much of an impact with this effort.  The $100k per day phone bills are the result of finding a weakness in your Asterisk configuration, GUI code, extension passwords, etc.  To really prevent those have a look here [Voip Info - Asterisk Security](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+security)

Comment: Thank you @telium. I was tending towards **rsync** anyway - you've convinced me! The **log files** are just for the end users to see what area code called, at what time, what they selected and how long they listened.

I think (hope!) the **security** of the pbx is OK. It has no outgoing auth and my losses at the SIP trunk provider are limited to the £1 of demo calling credit I got when I opened the account. The SIP ports themselves have been changed, the ACL blocks all except the SIP provider.

I tried to "upvote" your answer but I don't have enough rep yet. I'll do it as soon as I can!